# Unable to sign electron app for Windows on Mac using electron-builder

Tags: windows, macos, electron, electron-builder

I'm using `electron-builder@20.0.6` to sign a Windows app on my Mac.

Config in `package.json`:

```
"win": {
    "icon": "public/icon-win.png",
    "certificateFile": "win.p12",
    "certificatePassword": "xxx",
    "publisherName": "xxx"
},
```

When the signing step happens, it fails to sign the app using the provided certificate and password, which I have confirmed to be correct.

This is the full stack trace:

```
yarn run v1.3.2
$ /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/.bin/electron-builder -w
  • electron-builder version=20.0.6
  • loaded configuration file=package.json ("build" field)
  • loaded parent configuration preset=react-cra
  • writing effective config file=dist/electron-builder.yaml
  • rebuilding native production dependencies platform=win32 arch=x64
  • rebuilding native dependency name=fsevents
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=1.8.2 appOutDir=dist/win-unpacked
  • signing         file=dist/win-unpacked/XXX.exe certificateFile=win.p12
Error: Exit code: 255. Command failed: /Users/dima/Library/Caches/electron-builder/winCodeSign/winCodeSign-1.9.0/darwin/10.12/osslsigncode -in /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/dist/win-unpacked/XXX.exe -out /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/dist/win-unpacked/XXX-signed-sha1.exe -t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll -pkcs12 win.p12 -h sha1 -n XXX -i http://./ -pass b055944f51fd0c104493963cbd386dfca19e6608862d282279d2b1572ef81f66 (sha256 hash) failed(PKCS7_add_signature)

Failed

Signing failed(PKCS7_add_signature)

Failed

    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:124:16
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:282:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
From previous event:
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
From previous event:
    at doSign (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/windowsCodeSign.js:128:22)
    at defaultExecutor (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/windowsCodeSign.ts:61:12)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/windowsCodeSign.ts:68:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
From previous event:
    at sign (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/windowsCodeSign.js:51:21)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/winPackager.ts:250:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
From previous event:
    at WinPackager.doSign (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/winPackager.js:348:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/winPackager.ts:238:16
From previous event:
    at WinPackager.sign (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/winPackager.js:328:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/winPackager.ts:327:16
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
From previous event:
    at WinPackager.signAndEditResources (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/winPackager.js:405:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/winPackager.ts:343:18
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
From previous event:
    at WinPackager.signApp (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/winPackager.js:423:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:211:16
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
From previous event:
    at WinPackager.doPack (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/platformPackager.js:268:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:115:16
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
From previous event:
    at WinPackager.pack (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/platformPackager.js:188:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:372:24
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at xfs.stat (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/mkdirs.js:56:16)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:287:18
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
From previous event:
    at Packager.doBuild (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/packager.js:441:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:316:52
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:99:16
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:43:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
From previous event:
    at Packager._build (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/packager.js:385:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:278:23
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
From previous event:
    at Packager.build (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/packager.js:341:11)
    at /Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/index.ts:50:40
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
From previous event:
    at build (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder-lib/out/index.js:47:21)
    at build (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder/src/builder.ts:228:10)
    at then (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder/src/cli/cli.ts:48:33)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
From previous event:
    at Object.args [as handler] (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder/src/cli/cli.ts:48:33)
    at Object.runCommand (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:235:44)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1042:24)
    at Object.get [as argv] (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:957:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dima/workspace/work/XXX/node_modules/electron-builder/src/cli/cli.ts:42:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had not installed the Intermediate Certificated. Without having that in the certificate hierarchy, your certificate will not be valid and the signing process will fail.

It's the Microsoft Authenticode cert here, the very last one:

https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=INFO4690